# How far away can one be when tight line nymphing?

Tags: fly-fishing, trout-fishing

I've been experimenting with tight line nymphing and have had good success in murky/choppy water that allows me to get close to the trout without spooking them. However I'm reluctant to use these techniques when the water clear as when casting further I feel like I get a lot of sag/drag. How far away can one realistically fish when tight light nymphing?

Comment: Czech nymphing rods are usually a bit longer, the one I use is 10ft long and makes it much easier to stay connected to your line without the sag. If the line is sagging then it defeats the purpose!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really you are only limited by rod length. [This piece covers it a bit](https://www.tcoflyfishing.com/blogs/connect/euro-nymphing-rods-explained). One alternative for fishing those conditions would be to use a striker indicator which might not exactly be tight line nymphing, but can be effective nonetheless.

Comment: Thanks I've found that problem with sag when fishing at distance was reduced by using a longer leader with a lighter butt section.

Comment: that will help, for sure. But it is limited to how much leader you want to have out.